# I want to add address in a specific Phone Contact

Tags: swift, append, contacts, addressbook, cncontact

---

I have a list of contacts in table view cell whenever I click a cell which is an existing contact I want to add or update address in that existing contact.

var selectedContact: Contact!

> Contact! is a model

var updateContact = CNContact()

**Code for Updating Contact Address**

```
    func AddMultipleLocations(){
        
        var contact = CNMutableContact()
        contact = selectedAddress.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact

// error Value of type Contact has no member mutableCopy

contact.postalAddresses.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: homeAddress)) 
        print(homeAddress)
 do {
     let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
     saveRequest.update(contact)
     let contactstore = CNContactStore()
     try contactstore.execute(saveRequest)
self.showToast(message: "Contact Updated ", font: .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))
} catch let error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
   self.showToast(message: error.localizedDescription, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))}
```

Comment: Error Resolved by using updateContact instead of selectedcontact but I want to use selected contact to update my contact
 contact = updateContact.mutableCopy() as! CNMutableContact

Comment: This question is unclear. Please edit it and add enough context for us to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @burnsi is it clear now ?